# Should I mention future works in my SOP? (CS PhD Fall 2022 USA)

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, undergraduate, statement-of-purpose, machine-learning

**Background:** CS Undergrad applying to CS PhD Programs

I am working on my senior thesis and have thought about 2 major chapters. Assuming I apply to my preferred universities by dec 1st I will only be able to complete 1 chapter by then. Is it reasonable to discuss in short about how I plan to complete it within the SOP?

The topic I'm working on is something I want to continue working on during grad-school and is the professor's area of interest as well.

**Question** Is this something one should write about in their SOPs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact, your SOP should be more forward-looking than backward-looking. Spend as much of it as you can discussing your future work, research ideas and how *this department/professor in particular* will belp you achieve those goals.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was exactly what I was looking for!